# express router use meld to log request parameters and response

Tags: node.js, express, aop, meld

I use meld in my express project and I wanna log my api request with meld,This code below is my first try：

```
var meld = require('meld');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

var logger =  {
    apiAround:function(method){
        //TODO:log before request
        var result = method.proceed();
        //TODO:log after request
        return result;
    }
};
meld.around(router,'get',logger.apiAround);
router.get('/',function(req,res){
   //TODO:handle request 
});

app.use('/',router);
```

but it seems not work,what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem,actually I want to record my request param/response/response time,so this is code with middleware [response-time](https://github.com/expressjs/response-time)

```
var responseTime = require('response-time');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(responseTime(function(req,res,time){
    if(req.baseUrl.indexOf('/xxxxxx') !== -1)
    {
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log(time);
        console.log(res);
    }
}));
```